# Excel: Formula for dividing a number to 3 different cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently making an excel sheet for me and my roommates. We will use it for the payments and other fees in the house.

**What I had for the three cells `B9:B11` is this formula:**

`=IFERROR(SUMIFS(Register[Deposit (+)],Register[Name],[@Name])-SUMIFS(Register[Withdrawal (-)],Register[Name],[@Name]),"")`

**So what this formula does is:** If the data in `Name` column is `A`, the number in the `Withdrawal(-)` or `Deposit(+)` would be added or subtracted in his `Individual Balance`. It is the same for the `Individual Balance` of `B` and `C`.

**What I would like to do here is:**

If the `Name` in the blue column is `All`, I would like the numbers in the `Withdrawal(-)` or `Deposit(+)` section to be added or subtracted to the `Individual Balances` of `A`, `B`, and `C`.

**For example:**
In `D3`, the name is `All`, and the number in `Withdrawal(-)` is `$100`. I would like the `$100` to be divided to `A`, `B`, and `C`.

So `A`, `B`, and `C`'s `Individual Balances` would be `-$33.33`.

But since `A`, `B`, and `C` had `Deposit(+)` `$33.33` each `H4:H6` their Individual Balances in `B9:B11` should show `$0.00`.

**Question:** What should I add in my formula so that if I put `All` in the `Name` column, the number would be divided to the three individual balances?

[image: Excel]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the second sumif formula is subtracting G4 from person A, rather than from the ALL.

You need to adjust the second half of the SUMIFS to subtract from "ALL/3" instead of searching for the Register[Name],[@Name].  That will only subtract the G4, G5 and G6 cells which = 0.

Here is something I came up with, not sure it will work but I hope so.

> =IFERROR(SUMIFS(Register[Deposit (+)],Register[Name],[@Name])-SUMIF(Register[Name],"All",Register[Withdrawal
>   (-)])/3,"")

Comment: I think I have to clarify what I have written above, because For example: if I put another `All` in the `Name` column `D7` and put `$3.00` on `Withdrawal(-)` that formula would not work anymore. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: I got what you mean. However, is there a formula to make it easier? Like if we put `All` in the `Name` column, it would automatically divide the numbers in the `G` or `H` column to the three `Individual Balance`s instead of putting the formula every time?

Comment: I deleted my comment after I understood you better.  I edited my answer to explain the error in your formula.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort for understanding my question. But the formula `=IFERROR(SUMIFS(Register[Deposit (+)],Register[Name],[@Name])-SUMIFS(Register[Withdrawal (-)],Register[Name],[@Name]),"")` is written on cells `B9:B11` (The formula works well, except that it lacks a formula for `All` to work). I do not have any formula in cells of `C` to `H`, except for `H1`. Also, there might also be a time where numbers will be added in three `Individual Balances`. _Example_ I input `All` in cell `D7` and put `$9.00` in `H7`. I would like the `$9.00` to be divided to person `A`, `B`, and `C`.

Comment: I hope I did not make it more confusing. And I really appreciate your help! Thank you.

Comment: A very easy fix would be to create a total at the bottom and divide this by 3 :)  I am working on your formula, but it is not doing the same format in my Icelandic Excel for whatever reason.  One thing to note, I think using SUMIF would be much easier since you only have one criteria.  In a new cell, such as B13, try a "sumif" and go through the wizard and then divide the outcome by 3.  Make sure to add another "ALL" so that you know its working.

Comment: I just edited my answer again with a formula that might work.

Comment: I tried using the formula you gave but it doesn't work on my Excel. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157697/discussion-between-karl-kristjansson-and-dianna).